# Figure in Beamer

Tags: beamer, positioning, quoting

I want to make slide using `beamer`. Is it possible figure is in the top left side and quote is in the top right side of the figure? Is there any special environment 
for quote?

```
\begin{frame}[t]{Factorization Methods}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{gauss.jpeg}
\end{figure}

\textbf{``The problem of distinguishing prime numbers from composites, and of resolving composite numbers into their prime factors, is one of the most important and useful in all of arithmetic."}- Carl Friedrich Gauss



\vspace*{10pt}

\begin{itemize}
\item Pollard's $p-1$ algorithm (1974)
\vspace*{10pt}
\item Dixon's Random Squares Algorithm (1981)
\vspace*{10pt}
\item Quadratic Sieve (QS): Pomerance (1981)
\vspace*{10pt}
\item Williams' $p+1$ method (1982)
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do not need a `figure` environment to use `\includegraphics`. To place the image on the left and quote on the right, you can use for example `beamer`s `columns`, or a normal `tabular`. Both are demonstrated below.

By default a `p` column has justified text. By adding `\raggedright\arraybackslash` at the beginning of the cell, the text is set with left justification only.

If you want to align the top of the image with the top of the image, you can use the `adjustbox` package and its `\adjincludegraphics[valign=t]{image}` to set the 'anchor' of the image at the top, and also use `[t]` as an optional argument to the `columns` environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{array} % needed for \arraybackslash
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox} % for \adjincludegraphics
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Factorization Methods}

\begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
\adjincludegraphics[width=.8\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.7\textwidth}
\textbf{``The problem of distinguishing prime numbers from composites, and of resolving composite numbers into their prime factors, is one of the most important and useful in all of arithmetic."}

\hfill-- Carl Friedrich Gauss
\end{column}
\end{columns}


\vspace*{10pt}

\begin{itemize}
\item Pollard's $p-1$ algorithm (1974)
\vspace*{10pt}
\item Dixon's Random Squares Algorithm (1981)
\vspace*{10pt}
\item Quadratic Sieve (QS): Pomerance (1981)
\vspace*{10pt}
\item Williams' $p+1$ method (1982)
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Factorization Methods}

\begin{tabular}{p{.3\textwidth} p{.7\textwidth}}
\adjincludegraphics[width=.8\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image}
&
\raggedright\arraybackslash\textbf{``The problem of distinguishing prime numbers from composites, and of resolving composite numbers into their prime factors, is one of the most important and useful in all of arithmetic."}

\hfill-- Carl Friedrich Gauss
\end{tabular}



\vspace*{10pt}

\begin{itemize}
\item Pollard's $p-1$ algorithm (1974)
\vspace*{10pt}
\item Dixon's Random Squares Algorithm (1981)
\vspace*{10pt}
\item Quadratic Sieve (QS): Pomerance (1981)
\vspace*{10pt}
\item Williams' $p+1$ method (1982)
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]